Implementing pyramidal "half-voxels" to smooth terrain (not marching cubes)
I need pointers and advice about this idea. I know next to nothing about coding, but I like to design games and come from the art side. I'm designing a survival 3d game which so far doesn't feature destructible terrain. I want to make sort of a Minecraft clone, but with a slanted kind of block, which joins regular blocks, as to give the terrain a smoother appearance. I'll present a crude drawing as an example.

As you can see, the use of this shape would let me shape the terrain in a smoother yet low poly aesthetic. Is this easy to do? I haven't seen anyone do it this simply, most people use marching cubes or dual contouring for somewhat similar effects, but those are way above my level of coding expertise.

"Easy" is subjective. What specific help do you need in pulling this off? What have you tried so far, where have you gotten stuck, and what do you need from us to get you over that hurdle?
